# Java Framework similar to CodeIgniter

Tags: java, codeigniter, jakarta-ee, frameworks

Are there any Java EE  frameworks that are similar to CodeIgniter for PHP?

I need to convert a PHP web app to Java for my company.  (This is because they want to deploy the app on a Heroku Server)  Currently, the application uses the CodeIgniter framework.  This is my first Java EE project and I am in the process of learning JSF right now, but while I am doing that, I would like to know of possible frameworks that I should be looking at/ considering for this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure abt Heroku deployment, but Spring is a very capable f/w in Java. For small to medium size apps, Play f/w is also a good option.